# Blender game engine importing .obj error

Tags: game-engine

i have some .obj model files, which i wanted to use for a game in Blender. Sadly there are some problematic issues. When i start the game engine, the model seems to be sort of inside out...? My first thought were normals, which are flipped or wrong otherwise, but even that doesn't seem to be the problem. In addition to that, i found out that this wrong look is only sometimes when i start the game player, not every time...

I really don't know what i am doing wrong here...

Here is a picture of how it should look like (the front at least):
[image: Right model]

And here is a picture from the wrong model (notice that i just started the game player again, i changed nothing...):
[image: Wrong model]

At the second picture you can see the bottom of the model from the inside or something. Sometimes you see like an overlapping kind of scenario...

Does someone know if this is just a bug or how i can fix it?

You can download the corresponding .blend file here:
http://www.mediafire.com/file/dqm8woo2nmo639a/Shiptest.blend/file

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide the blend file, it will be easier to diagnose. It seems you launch the game in Texture mode instead of Material, maybe that's a part of th issue ? (Display Mode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The imported material is set as transparent. The selected transparency method, "Z transparency", give weird results if the object has internal geometry.

To fix this, in the material properties, uncheck "Transparency".

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/71575)

Comment: The question is "how can i fix it", and my answer fix it. Maybe should I add some explanations ?

Comment: Yes, a little context and a short explanation of the issue and why this fixes it should suffice

Comment: This was really the answer... i didn't expected it to be this easy :) But why though? It was all set to 100%. Does only checking it results into these troubles!?